# Limiting Kismet log files to a size or duration

Tags: linux, database, sqlite, logging, kismet-wireless

Looking for a solid way to limit the size of Kismet's database files (*.kismet) through the conf files located in /etc/kismet/.  The version of Kismet I'm currently using is 2021-08-R1.

The end state would be to limit the file size (10MB for example) or after X minutes of logging the database is written to and closed.  Then, a new database is created, connected, and starts getting written to.  This process would continue until Kismet is killed.  This way, rather than having one large database, there will be multiple smaller ones.

In the kismet_logging.conf file there are some timeout options, but that's for expunging old entries in the logs.  I want to preserve everything that's being captured, but break the logs into segments as the capture process is being performed.

I'd appreciate anyone's input on how to do this either through configuration settings (some that perhaps don't exist natively in the conf files by default?) or through plugins, or anything else.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Two interesting ways:

One could let the old entries be taken out, but reach in with SQL and extract what you wanted as a time-bound query.

A second way would be to automate the restarting of kismet... which is a little less elegant.. but seems to work.

https://magazine.odroid.com/article/home-assistant-tracking-people-with-wi-fi-using-kismet/

If you read that article carefully... there are lots of bits if interesting information here.